# showing large image in firebase notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova, firebase

I am doing one Cordova application where I want to show large image in notification when we expand it ( When app is background ). Even I tired like this also from console.

```
{ "data": { "image": "https://static.pexels.com/photos/4825/red-love-romantic-flowers.jpg", "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API" "AnotherActivity": "True" }, "to" : "device id Or Device token" }
```

In data, I can see image link but its not showing in notification.
Even I tried in some other ways, but no use.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello Ganesh, to show image in firebase push notification you can refer this tutorial...http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: ok will check thanks

Comment: @JaiminPrajapti can I have sample for iOS because I don't know android and he is sending from php right? I am testing in console by adding image url in data